# Does the sequence $X_n$ converge in probability or almost surely?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am a bit confused about how I should solve the question below and was wondering if someone would like to help me with how to think?

> Consider the sequence $(X_n)_{n≥1}$, defined as: $X_n$​ takes the
> value $1$ if $n=2^k$, and $0$ otherwise. Determine if the sequences
> converge in probability or converge almost surely (or none).

My first thought was that, as n increases, the probability of $X_n$ being $1$ becomes smaller and smaller and hence $X_n$ converges in probability to $0$, because $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(|X_n-0|\ge\epsilon)=0$.

But then I started thinking that the probability of Xn being $1$ or $0$ does not change as n increases; it depends solely on whether n is a power of $2$ or not. This probability remains the same for each n. So maybe the sequence does not converge neither in probability nor almost surely?

And now I am at a standpoint where I don't know which way is the correct way to think in this case. Does anybody want to help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

**Note**: I think that I have already concluded that $X_n$ does not converge almost surely since there are infinitely many values of n for which $X_n$ = $1$.

Comment: It feels a bit strange to ask about convergence of sequence of random variables that are actually constant, but you are right, they don't converge neither in probability nor almost surely. (more precisely, probability of $X_n$ being $1$ changes as $n$ increases, but it doesn't converge to anything, it flips between $0$ and $1$)

Comment: @mihaild Yes, I thought that it was a bit strange too, hence my confusion. Thank you for your help and clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second intuition is correct.  One subsequence is constant and therefore converges in both probability and almost surely to the constant random variable $1$, while another is constant and converges in both ways to the constant $0$.

Therefore there can be no single random variable to which the entire sequence converges, in either sense, since convergence in either sense is preserved by subsequences.